# Search bar in Windows 10 plain doesn't work (and other assorted functions)

Tags: windows, windows-10, search, repair, file-search

No, this issue didn't appear after an update. The search function features are also still there, they just don't start.
I know reinstalling Windows fixes most things, I just wanted a second opinion on these too.

### The backstory

A few weeks ago I started getting I/O_INITIALIZATION_FAILED on bootup, so I did what I do and rebuilt some boot features, which fixed the error. **However,** this didn't fix some things. The most prevalent issue is the Search Bar in the Start Menu. The files are there, but they don't start. I can't search for files in this bar, because it doesn't load. I can't search for files in the File Explorer either. More underlying issues were there too, like certain Control Panel items wouldn't open up, REGEDIT sometimes didn't open, the CPU would max out for no reason with a System program, etc. Using the built-in repair and Windows 10 Installation Media repair tool didn't help either. It just said it could be started, and proceeded to close.

### What I think I should do

I think I just need to reinstall Windows and go through the process of backup/reinstall. It should just reinstall every file where it needs to be, and save me a whole lot of trouble.

### What I want to know

Is there a program perhaps, or a system utility, besides reinstalling, that I could check my installation with? Perhaps I could diagnose it?

### Other

Some more minor clarifications: This didn't start happening after an update. This started after bluescreens. That rules out the [duplicate] tag for those issues. I can also type in the search bar, but no results show up, the window stays empty. I mentioned the other programs. They either run after 1 hour+ of loading or just literally don't open (with *no* error messages!)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I am not sure what might have happened and there seems to be more that one thing wrong.

That said, run a Windows 10 Repair Install (steps below) and start with the first one: Keep Everything.

If Windows Repair does not work, then there is enough gone wrong, that you should back up and re-install Windows.

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/software-download/windows10

Windows 10 is running, so click on the Download button (not Upgrade Button) and select Run.
If the Repair will not run as per above, use the Download button to create a USB Windows Installation key,
then run Setup on the USB Key.

This will launch the Repair and proceed normally.  There are 3 ways to proceed, according to the severity of the error.

(1) Keep Everything: Best if it works and your computer comes back just the way you had set it up except repaired.  Always have a backup, but generally nothing will be lost.

(2) Keep Data: Necessary if the operating system damage is extensive. Keeps the User Profile and makes software install quite easy. Always have a backup, but data is not usually lost.

(3) Keep Nothing: Deletes the User Profile and all else and is essentially a fresh install.  Be certain you have backed up all your data. "Keep Nothing" is necessary if the User Profile is damaged, because broken User Profiles cannot be repaired and it is generally easier to back up and start over if the User Profile is damaged. It depends on the precise situation.

Comment: The Win10 Repair Tool in the boot disk didn't work. It said it couldn't start. Odd, right? I'll edit my question to add that.

Comment: Yes, seems odd because I have used Windows Repair a number of times.  So now, your option is to back everything up and reinstall Windows.  Answer edited to that effect.

Comment: Guess I'll have to go nuclear. Thanks for your help, though!